# How to take off html elements from Content Keywords in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: html, seo, keyword, google-search-console

I have found a template. However, in the webmaster tools, HTML elements take over keywords. Why is this happening? I believe there's a problem in the HTML code of the template. How do I take off html elements from the Content Keywords in Webmaster Tools?

Here's the website if you'd like to see the HTML:

http://www.bestoffernet.com

And here's a picture of the problem:

[image: Keywords problem]

Comment: Read the [tag:seo] tag wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a lot display:none text in your pages.

```html
<textarea id="postData-754007445393546837" style="display:none;">
"<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-LZTWB3mlaxk/VpeeYNcxCPI/AAAAAAAAAxw/fjihGJEuLG8/s1600/surf-internet-at-500Mbps.jpg" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="Surf the internet at 500 Mbps" border="0" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-LZTWB3mlaxk/VpeeYNcxCPI/AAAAAAAAAxw/fjihGJEuLG8/s1600/surf-internet-at-500Mbps.jpg" title=""/></a></div>
<br/>
Many people around the world have a slow connection and in order to see a page like this one, they take a whole cup of coffee while it's loading for them. Unfortunately, This tutorial isn't for them, because, in fact, this trick requires a good connection which is not necessarily fast.<br/>
<br/>
If you like to see pages loading faster, willing to download or upload very big files, or only looking for a way to unlock a blocked website in your country or area, etc. then you've come to the right place.<br/>
<br/>
<h2>
How to surf the internet at the speed 500 Mbps?</h2>
<div>
In order to surf the internet at 500 Mbps, you just need to register in <a href="https://rabb.it/">Rabbit</a>. This is a chatting website that allows its users to use webcam, microphone or text only. But, we can also use it as a browser to surf the internet! Here's how to do it.</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
1) Go to <a href="https://rabb.it/">Rabbit</a> then click on <b>Sign up, </b>after that choose the way you like to register your new account.</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
2) Confirm your account by clicking on the link you've received on your email</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
3) Once registered, the website will ask you the following question "How do you want to Rabbit? Take your pick:", Here, choose <b>Messages only.</b> COOL! After that, you just need to click on <b>Rabbitcast Launchpad </b>(see the following picture)</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hV53PQ3arBU/VpekXYVVAoI/AAAAAAAAAyE/pDrUetwohKI/s1600/Rabbitcast_launcher.PNG" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="Rabbitcast Launchpad" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hV53PQ3arBU/VpekXYVVAoI/AAAAAAAAAyE/pDrUetwohKI/s1600/Rabbitcast_launcher.PNG" title=""/></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br/></div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
4) When you click on it, a new notification will appear asking you to choose from a list of suggested websites like Youtube, Hulu and Netflix. Or you can merely enter any website you wish. I tried Bestoffernet.com<br/>
<br/></div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-G39vh4bOWZo/VpelogYhpuI/AAAAAAAAAyQ/wFKOZC_c3A4/s1600/bestoffernet_on_rabbit.PNG" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="Bestoffernet on rabbit" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-G39vh4bOWZo/VpelogYhpuI/AAAAAAAAAyQ/wFKOZC_c3A4/s1600/bestoffernet_on_rabbit.PNG" title=""/></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
5) Here's how it looks like in the browser: ( if you don't like the quality of the image, turn it from LD to HD)</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ozsW_Zhc1ZE/VpemlYXnZ_I/AAAAAAAAAyc/kMSqZRw7K8M/s1600/part_of_the_website.PNG" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="bestoffernet.com on rabbit" border="0" height="261" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ozsW_Zhc1ZE/VpemlYXnZ_I/AAAAAAAAAyc/kMSqZRw7K8M/s320/part_of_the_website.PNG" title="" width="320"/></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<br/></div>
<div>
So, this is the best way to watch youtube videos at 1080p HD on a slow connection, without interruptions.</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
I tried "speed test" and here is the result, the speed exceeds 500 Mbps:</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-egxnQj6cXog/Vpeo0LiWOWI/AAAAAAAAAys/XTz-LPw94xM/s1600/Speedtest_rabbit.PNG" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="speed test" border="0" height="46" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-egxnQj6cXog/Vpeo0LiWOWI/AAAAAAAAAys/XTz-LPw94xM/s320/Speedtest_rabbit.PNG" title="" width="320"/></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<br/></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<br/></div>
<div>
Note that this service works just like a VPS. You can download files, save them and then upload them to services like Dropbox in a very short time.</div>
<div>
<br/></div>
<div>
I hope you like this trick which is not going to last for a long period, so enjoy it!</div>
<div>
If you have any question or anything, don't hesitate to use the comment box below. I will be glad to hear from you.</div>
</textarea>
```

```html
Godaddy</h2>
GoDaddy is one of the biggest hosting and domain name registrar companies on the internet today. Its services are so popular and widespread that even those who are not concerned about web hosting and domain names have surely heard about it in some way.<br/>
<br/>
Some statistics shows that GoDaddy, in 2014, had more than 59 million domain names and is constantly growing, making it the world's largest ICANN-accredited registrar. <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy">Wikipedia</a><br/>
<br/>
In short, services on GoDaddy are of high caliber and the 12 million customers they serve cannot be wrong. I personally tried their services and I'm more than satisfied.<br/>
<br/>
<h2>
Coupon Code $0.99 Domain Name
I'm writing this article for people looking for coupon codes with which they can get a high-quality domain name such as ".COM , .NET or CO.UK ," and many others, at a reduced priced.<br/>
```

What you need to do is remove all those. Forget about removing them from just the Content Keyword Report they are there because they are acutaly words in you html.

So the reason this report is on your search console is because you ACTUALY have all this text on your page. And at the same time it is considered a bad SEO practice from your site.

Comment: Hello George, thanks so much for the answer it's very helpful. by the way, those are not ads, but articles that I've already published. But I don't know why they are present in the homepage, I think this is a bad template. I better change it.

Comment: Indeed you have ! Sometimes i get so focus on the source code that i don't even consider the front page content. I changed my answer a bit so it doesn't have misleading hypothesis by my part.

Comment: I don't know why in my web, the top ranking of Keywords is "thumb", "thumb" in my web is a class name and part of file names...¿? www.cave-canem.cat/ca/home/animals/1/6

Comment: Courious: If I search in google "teckel thumb" my web is in first position!! my web is only 2 month old!!! but... why?